# Post to and display web page from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, post

I want to post to a web page from my Silverlight application and have the web page appear in a new window.

I can show a web page in a new window using the GET method, using the following code:

```
var options = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions();
HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri("http://localhost:12345/test.aspx"), "_blank", options);
```

I can post to a web page and get the resulting data back using this code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:12345/test.aspx"));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.BeginGetRequestStream(requestResult =>
{
    using (var stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(requestResult))
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write("hello");
        }
    }

    request.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
    {
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }, null);
}, null);
```

But what I can't do is the two together - post to the page but instead of getting the data back have the resulting page shown in a browser window. I don't know if this is possible, but any help to achieve this would be much appreciated.